# Why is the code not working if ID starts with number?

Tags: html, css

Yesterday I spent about an hour for searching for any mistypes in my code,I have the same code many times already in it,but for some reason this one did not work  as it supposed to do(the code is not actually important, it's just to show you what I mean)

```
<div class="popup" onmouseover="popup-()">
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup-">Click for more</span>

<button onclick="338reconM()"> <img id="338recon" 
src="338recon.png.png"/>338-Recon</button></div>
<input type="button" id="338reconB" title="Weapon stats"value="Weapon info" 
onclick="location.href='http://symthic.com/bf4-weapon-info?w=338-Recon'";/>

#338recon{
display:block;
}

#338reconB{
color:gray;
background-color:Transparent;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border: none;
cursor:pointer;
overflow: hidden;
}
#338reconB:hover{
color:red;
border:1px solid;
}
```

Then I'd realized that this image was the only one, that had its ID started with numbers(there are 43 other images that worked with this code), do I decided to make that ID recon338, and it did work, that was the problem
But why is that a problem? Could someone actually tell me why an ID can't start with number?

Comment: I does not take anything more than typing “html css id start with number” or similar into Google to find https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/ or https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/ ... please make more of an effort before asking.

Comment: function names like `338reconM` or `popup-` are invalid. As in all languages: function names must not start with number. Also in JS `-` is not valid character for names. And ID on element can be referred with JS variable of same name directly, so also not valid

Comment: So there's nothing special reason? This programming language has been coded like this that's all then?

Comment: @CBroe I saw that page, but I asked it here because I just wanted to know if there's any special reason for it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put `#\` before the number in your css

```
#\33 38reconB:hover{
color:red;
border:1px solid;
}
```

if found this answer here: https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/